# Get All the week days from a given Week Number in Sql Server?

Tags: sql-server-2008

is it possible to get all the dates of a week by a given week number lets say I provide week number 2 from year 2011 and can I get all the week days starting from the first monda?

Comment: can you clarify where/how you are going to use this?

Comment: Is week 1 the ISO week or the first week with a Monday?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work:

```
SET DATEFIRST 1
DECLARE @wk int SET @wk = 2
DECLARE @yr int SET @yr = 2011

--define start and end limits
DECLARE @todate datetime, @fromdate datetime
SELECT @fromdate = dateadd (week, @wk, dateadd (YEAR, @yr-1900, 0)) - 4 -
         datepart(dw, dateadd (week, @wk, dateadd (YEAR, @yr-1900, 0)) - 4) + 1
SELECT @todate = @fromdate + 6

;WITH DateSequence( Date ) AS
(
    SELECT @fromdate AS Date
        UNION ALL
    SELECT dateadd(DAY, 1, Date)
        FROM DateSequence
        WHERE Date < @todate
)

--select result
SELECT * FROM DateSequence OPTION (MaxRecursion 1000)
```

It's patched up on bits and pieces found around the internet and will generate this result:

```
Date
-----------------------
2011-01-10 00:00:00.000
2011-01-11 00:00:00.000
2011-01-12 00:00:00.000
2011-01-13 00:00:00.000
2011-01-14 00:00:00.000
2011-01-15 00:00:00.000
2011-01-16 00:00:00.000
```

There's most likely better ways to do it though.